# Bootstrap nested columns in row do not align with columns in previous row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my nested column (col-md-6) I included two rows. Unfortunately the (smaller) pictures in the second row do not horizontally align to the left with the first column and the rest of the whole page content. Is there any different margin in col-md-4 than in col-md-12 or is is there any other reason?

Thank you!

```
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-height">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <a href="images/e1/expose1.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
             <img src="images/e1/expose1.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive" width="100%">
           </a>
           blabla
        </div>
     </div>
     <div clas="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <a href="images/e1/s1.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
              <img src="images/e1/s1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <img src="images/e1/s2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <img src="images/e1/s3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" >
        </div>      
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demo with what you tried sofar?

Comment: three `col-4`s *should* exactly equal one `col-12` - so if there's an issue with not lining up the same, I'd be looking at padding or margins on all the other things first.

Comment: http://mitadu.de/bs/test.html is this OK? Maybe someone can also tell me why several JS scripts (e.g. lightbox) don't work.

Comment: FYI: its the three smaller pictures below the large image. they left one of those smaller images seems to have a padding or something. there's also a padding if I simply put text.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because of the `img-thumbnail` class you are using on the last two images.

Try converting them to `img-responsive`

Comment: They also dont line up, if I simply put text